# viewDidload and viewDidAppear not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, viewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers and a container view controller. I add those 3 view controllers as child view controllers in the container. When I launch the app I have print statements in viewDidload and viewDidAppear in all the view controllers which get executed.

The problem is: When I "scroll" back on those views and it "appears" again the print statements do not execute nor any code inside viewDidAppear nor viewDidLoad. Why is this happening?

Here is my code where I instantiate my view controllers. Thanks for the help!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self



    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    page1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIdentifiers.feedViewController.rawValue) as! FeedViewController
    page1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    page1.delegate = self
    scrollView.addSubview(page1.view)
    addChildViewController(page1)
    page1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    page2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIdentifiers.favoritesViewController.rawValue) as! FavoritesViewController
    page2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    page2.delegate = self
    scrollView.addSubview(page2.view)
    addChildViewController(page2)
    page2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    page3 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIdentifiers.settingsViewController.rawValue) as! SettingsViewController
    page3.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(page3.view)
    addChildViewController(page3)
    page3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What would trigger those view **controllers** to cycle through their life cycles?

The parent view controller, whatever it's named will run through it's load cycle. All views will also run through their. (I bet if you subclass a view and, using it, put a breakpoint inside draw(rect:) it would hit it.) But there's nothing to trigger the child view controllers to do their thing.

From what I see, your view hierarchy is:

- Main view
- Scroll view inside main view
- Three page views inside scroll view

When the main view (the afore-mentioned parent view controller) loads, it goes through the usual `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillLoadSubviews`.... and it's **there** that all of the above views get loaded, laid out, and drawn.

Nothing is happening to trigger those three page controllers to do any loading.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and you are right with your bullet points. So from my understanding as I scroll to the 3 view controllers that are inside the scroll view , viewDidAppear etc would not get triggered again since they have been loaded? Even if I scroll to the again? ( really new to this!) Also I thought "What would trigger those view controllers to cycle through their life cycles?" would be when I scrolled on that certain view it would cause it to execute. But I guess not?

Comment: I tried asking this before in your previous question - what is the reason for those 3 VCs? Don't confuse UIViews with UIViewControllers. (It's a common mistake for newbies, and I'm saying this with respect to you.) The way thing work is the "parent VC" controls the scroll view **and** all the views within it. In an old version of my app I had a UIPageView and a UIScrollView that worked with two GLKViews (similar to UIViews) inside it. All of it - loading the images, the scroll window, altering the page control - was worked on with a single UIViewController. I'll add to this....

Comment: I offloaded the image processing to functions in a Framework because I wanted to share that code. I offloaded the auto layout to another file. I moved the processing of the scroll view and page view delegates to a UIViewController extension. Otherwise, you'd have a massive view controller. I also made a few other extensions also. But the main point of these two comments is - I think unless you have a **specific need** (and there may be one) to have your views in your scroll view to have their own controller, you are headed down a path with unintended side effects.

Comment: I'm not sure what time zone you are in, but if you like I'll try to get some code together from that old version of my app (I have things in a private GitHub repository). I'm not available for the next 12 hours so it may be around 14-16 before I get things set up. Keep this question open. I'll post a link when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks for the great comments! I will wait for your code sample here. Essentially I have 3 view controllers because one takes care of a collection view, another a tableview and the last one is a settings screen. I then added these 3 to the container view ( code sample above). =]